# How to get MAC address of NIC connected to a Cisco switch?

Tags: networking, switch, cisco

I would like to know if it is possible to get the MAC address of the network card attached to a Cisco 5010 switch. If it is possible how do you do it? What commands do I need to use?

In my case the host I would like to discover the MAC address of is on port #6.

Comment: If this is a managed switch, then "maybe".  If this is an unmanaged switch, then "no".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`show mac address-table dynamic` command](http://www.scribd.com/doc/50816068/446/show-mac-address-table-dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

To get only MAC addresses attached to the interface you are interested in, use:

`show mac address-table interface fa0/6`

Where fa0/6 is the interface you're interested in.